# why error " Syntax error on token "println", = expected " in the following code?

Tags: java

In the following code I  added some System.out.println statements so that i can see the changes of values of variables everytime . But I now am having error " Syntax error on token "println", = expected " , though I checked everything and coundn;t find any mistakes . And before adding those System.out.println statements , everything was ok .

Here is my code :

```
public class A{
  public static int temp = 4;
  //System.out.println("temp = "+temp);

  public int sum;
  System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
  public int y;
  System.out.println("y = " + y);
  public A(int x){
    y = temp - 2 +x;
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
    sum = temp + 3;
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    temp-=2;
    //System.out.println("temp = "+temp);
  }
  public void methodB(int m, int n){
    int x = 0;
    y = y + m + (temp++);
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
    x = x + 2 +  n;
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    sum = sum + x + y;
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println(x + " " + y+ " " + sum); 
  }


}


class B extends A {
  public int x;
  public int sum;
  System.out.println("sum = "+sum);
  public B(int p){
    super(p);
    y = temp + p ;
    System.out.println("y = "+y);
    sum = p+ temp + 1;
    System.out.println("sum = "+sum);
    temp-=1;
  }  
  public void methodB(int m, int n){    
    int  y =0;
    y = y + this.y; 
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
    x = this.y + 2 + temp;
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    super.methodB(x, y);
    sum = x + y + super.sum;
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println(x + " " + y+ " " + sum);
  }


}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    A a1 = new A(2);
    B b1 = new B(3);
    a1.methodB(1, 1);
    b1.methodB(1, 2);
    a1.methodB(3, 2);
    b1.methodB(2, 2);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have print statements outside of a method. In class A

```
System.out.println("temp = " + temp);
System.out.println("sum = " + sum); 
System.out.println("y = " + y);
```

need to be moved into a method. In class B

```
System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

needs to be moved into a method.

If you want to see what the default values of these variables are, just put these print statements first thing in your constructors like so

```
public A(int x){
    System.out.println("temp = " + temp);
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum); 
    System.out.println("y = " + y);

    y = temp - 2 + x;
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
    sum = temp + 3;
    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    temp -= 2;
    //System.out.println("temp = " + temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `System.out.println()` statements to a method, maybe your `main` method. They can't be called outside of a method.

Comment: If you aren't going to add anything more to the answer already provided, don't post another answer for no reason.